# one way object from controller to directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass object from controller to directive but not **two way binding**.

I tried with **JSON.stringify** and it work but in HTML it display whole data.

Is there any way around to achieve this?

In my controller:
    `$scope.obj= { selectedItems=[1,2,3]};`
In html:
    `<my-dir pass-obj= "obj"><my-dir>`
In directive:
    `scope:{passObj='@'}`

It give me string as "obj" not the object.

Comment: can't you use `@`?

Comment: this pass string only! I have to pass an object

Comment: `JSON.stringify` would pass it as a string as well, so your comment doesn't exactly clarify your problem.  Please post a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that I can use JSON.stringify but doesn't it will show all my object in string form on inspect element on browser?

Comment: @claies added some code..

Comment: that doesn't even look like valid syntax.  you can't use `=` inside an object declaration.

Comment: I update the attr name..

Comment: Use `<`. Make sure to read the documentation to understand what the rules are. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-

Comment: It doesn't work for older version...it is introduced in latest version.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of AngularJS one-way binding is done with `$watch`.

```
app.directive("myDir", function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            //one-way binding
            scope.$parent.$watch("attrs.passObj", function(newValue) {
                scope.passObj = newValue;
            });
        }
    };
 });
```

The above example is the equivalent of doing one-way binding with AngularJS 1.5:

```
 scope: { passObj: '<' }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

**controller:**

```
$scope.obj= { selectedItems=[1,2,3]};
```

**html:**

```
<my-dir passObj= "::obj"><my-dir>
```

It's been asked before, and you can read more here; [One-way binding in Angular directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777266/one-way-binding-in-angular-directives)

Comment: But this is one time binding and will not change if my controller obj change